# How many Cef.ChromiumBrowser instances to create inside application?

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

Our WPF application uses ChromiumBrowser instance to render html content. Our application has dashboard screen and four other screen which uses Chromium instances. These four screens are like following

1. Screen1: [OFFLINE] Launches local flash file(250MB-500MB) in Chromium.
2. Screen2: [ONLINE] Launches any website user enters in addressbar.
3. Screen3: [OFFLINE] Launches a heavy webapp into Chromium browser.
4. Screen4: [ONLINE] Launches you-tube video stream.

User can access screens in following way: http://postimg.org/image/rx9ovm7nf/

Currently we are creating new instance of chromium browser in each screens. Lets say user starts from Dashboard to screen1(new chromium instance), then come back to Dashboard we are disposing chromium. If user performs this frequently application is taking time to create chromium instance and dispose it when he comes back. If we don't dispose ChromiumSubProcess.exe is getting added in taskbar.

Our question is how to create and dispose chromium properly in our scenario? or how to use chromium in our current scenario? or best practices how to use chromium in the application?

Comment: Can you supply some code for what you're doing and maybe we can help optimize it

Comment: i think not required. my question is something related to architecture. :)

Comment: For someone to properly help you then providing source or an example of how to reproduce your problem is a must. Also what is `ChromiumSubProcess.exe`? It's not part of the `CefSharp` project.

Comment: Sorry, it is Cefsharp.BrowserSubproces.exe

Comment: @amaitland ok  i wil post the code. Meanwhile can you think of what are best practices to use Chromiun in WPF?

Comment: Best practice is to reuse the `ChromiumWebBrowser` instances where possible, remove them and `Dispose` of them when they're done. There isn't much more it it than that. If you make sure to specify a `CachePath` as part of the settings you initialize with then much of the expense of rendering a page are the network requests, so once they're cached things will speed up quite a lot.

Comment: Also check out the `WPF Example`, it demos lots of features, including being a tabbed browser. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/tree/cefsharp/47/CefSharp.Wpf.Example